# Vulgar way of saying "he killed himself"

Tags: expressions, offensive-language

I'm trying to translate my acquaintance's cartoon to cite it in an article written in English. For the subject of the article it is important that the translation will be direct, thus very vulgar (very offensive).

Is there a vulgar way of saying *he killed himself* in English meaning that someone died, but did not commit suicide nor was killed by someone else, for example fell out of balcony or touched high-voltage line (by accident)?

I've learned English for many years but I always have problem with understanding and using offensive words as this is not something they teach you at school or courses, so I will appreciate any help.

I can include the Polish expression my acquaintance used, but I don't think it is necessary or helpful.

Thank you for many comments and answers. I resolved from them additional requirements for this expression. It should be short (a short remark, like "He died.", but vulgar) and not imply the deceased person stupidity. It should only show disrespect in the way that you use vulgar expression making a remark about someone's death.

The Polish expression was *Zajebał się*. It's left not translated in Google Translate. The first word is from the word family of *jebać*, directly meaning *fuck*, and *się* is somewhat equivalent of *himself*. It does not imply death was connected with sexual activity, it's just being vulgar. The prefix *za* (in this context) means that the activity was completed.

Comment: "He killed himself" is the definition of *suicide*. Do you mean a way to express that he died of, uh, misadventure? Like the Darwin Awards?

Comment: I mean misadventure, like falling out of balcony. So you cannot use "he killed himself" for this situations?

Comment: No, like I said, "killed himself" means exactly the same thing as "committed suicide". The best I can come up with for "he died by accident" is, well, "he died". Which is rather broad and general: it doesn't specifically exclude murder or suicide.

Comment: "He killed himself" can be used for a suicide, or for an accidental death in which the victim's recklessness was a prevailing factor.

Comment: I don't think "he killed himself" necessarily means suicide. People kill themselves accidentally all the time -- radio falls lin the bathtub, balcony railing breaks, the shotgun they're cleaning goes off, etc.

Comment: @nuoritoveri, does the manner of death have to imply idiocy on the part of the deceased? Or would an "act of God" (say, being hit by lightning out of a clear blue sky) qualify? I think you need to clarify a bit more, and possibly go ahead and include the Polish expression, just in case.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by vulgar. Perhaps you can include the Polish expressions along with their English equivalents from Google Translate. Falling out of a window = Defenestration; Touching a HV line = Electrocution.

Comment: He came to a sticky end.

Comment: OK, according to my Polish-speaking colleage, *Zajebał się* means "He fucked himself." I voted to close because I don't think we want this kind of polling-for-vulgar-expressions question hitting the multicollider.

Comment: I think it is fascinating that proper English doesn't really have a vulgar word for death. We have to look to slang for something anywhere close to what OP wants.

Comment: @Robusto It can also mean what you say, but my interpretation is also possible. I added NSFW in the title, but coleopterist removed. Maybe it should be added again?

Comment: "fucked himself up", but that doesn't necessarily mean he died.

Comment: @Mr Lister but this interpretation (death) is possible? In the cartoon the person making the remark will be looking at the dead body, so the context will be rather clear.

Comment: If it's not his fault, then you can't really say he killed himself.

Comment: I think @StoneyB has a good one.

Comment: If you feel that implies too much fault to the decedent, you can cut "up".

Comment: @StoneyB I suggest you make that an answer. It seems to fit the bill. "Fucked up" = "made a BIG mistake"; "fucked" (without *up*) = "done for".

Comment: "Fucked" > "fucked up", but neither implies certain death.

Comment: I'm Polish native speaker, and I have to admit that I have never seen an equivalent word in English… which makes me think what kind of language Polish is :-). I don't find “fucked up” even half as offensive as the Polish word cited by OP…

Comment: This comment section reminds me of the [Parrot Sketch](http://www.davidpbrown.co.uk/jokes/monty-python-parrot.html)

Comment: Croaked? Not as vulgar as the original, but on the way.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party here, but the author Tim O'Brien is fond of saying *he ate shit* to mean someone died. It seems like a close match to me.

Comment: @Cameron I think it's the kind of thing I was looking for. I read that it can also mean a non-fatal accident, but the context of death will be explicit, so I think it really fits. It's short and offensive enough. If you could make your comment an answer I would choose it but unfortunately the question is closed now. By no means I wanted to provoke discussion, I just wanted to get a short answer. I regret I haven't provided enough details at the beginning, but maybe I'm not experienced enough in asking questions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An expression that gives me a not entirely healthy satisfaction and which I'll offer is:

> He bit the dust.

It's a very old phrase that means "he died", but it just sounds so damn pathetic.

EDIT: This just occurred to me after seeing the f-bombs dropped in the comments. I remember that Tommy and Turkish in the movie "Snatch" use the expression

> *He got proper fucked*

to refer to someone who's been killed. Actually, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1jgwi5cvoc) they're referring to a rabbit, but the idea's the same. [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=proper%20fucked) has a definition that doesn't do a whole lot of good, but it supports the idea that to be *fucked* could be bad, but to be *proper fucked* is terminal.

This term, to the best of my knowledge, is strictly British English.

Comment: Well, when you do yourself in by some sort of stupid or random accident, you die. That's why I chose bit the dust; it seems more apt for someone who unintentionally does themself in. This could go round and round though.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for something colloquial, and which does not imply stupidity, "*he offed himself*" is the closest I can think of. It does not appear to refer specifically to suicide [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off) and [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/off?s=t) (look only at the *verb* definitions), but others users may weigh in on whether it implies suicide or not.

Comment: I think this is typically used in relation to suicide.

Comment: @david.smith "He snuffed himself" might be better.

Comment: I think both are acceptable mobspeak. ;-)

Comment: "fell out of balcony or touched high-voltage line"  that's *went splat* and *got fried*, respectively. *intentionally* is an implied word in the phrase "he killed himself", otherwise he *was* killed *by* something, or *when* something happened, or simply *got* killed. IDC what the definitions say; colloquially, ""he killed himself"" is suicide without further context: *'He killed himself when he drove off a bridge to avoid a deer'*, is not, however it's poor wording. *'He died in a car accident WHEN [...]'*, would be better. +1 for answering the title.

Answer (score 7):

If the literal sense of the original is “He’s fucked himself”, but you want to avoid explicitly attributing the death to any specific or deliberate agency, you might consider:

> “He’s fucked”, where the comedy will lie chiefly in the complete inadequacy of the expression to the situation.
>
> “He’s *really* fucked”, where the comedy will lie in the speaker's attempt to raise his normal inarticulateness to meet the situation.
>
> “He’s *really* fucked this time”, which will suggest that the victim is of a sort to whom such things routinely happen, just not quite this bad.
>
> “He’s *really* fucked up this time”, which will suggest that the victim has excelled his usual ability to draw catastrophe on his own head.

Comment: These certainly satisfy the vulgarity requirement, but it should be noted that they don't necessarily describe a deadly situation. I could use this same language to decribe, say, when someone uses REPLY ALL to send a compromising response he thought would be read by only one person, or getting into a minor car accident with a suspended license and no insurance, or realizing that the woman he just had a one-night stand with happens to be his boss's daughter.

Comment: @J.R. Look at the comments and it appears we're not really asked to "describe a deadly situation". **a)** The language in the original is "Zajebał się" translated without contradiction by OP as "He fucked himself." **b)** OP describes the visual: "In the cartoon the person making the remark will be looking at the dead body, so the context will be rather clear." Since I posted OP has indicated a willingness to accept Cameron's suggestion of *he ate shit* as "short and offensive enough."

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't trying to pick apart your answer, I was just hoping to elaborate on it a little bit more, from an English perspective.

Comment: @J.R.  I didn't think you were. This was messy because the ground kept shifting; I posted another answer and then deleted. Sometimes questioners are just like Clients.

Answer (score 2):

A few creative options come to mind:

- He removed himself from the gene pool.
- He committed stupidcide.
- He died of jackassery. *(This suggestion is a play on words off [this TV show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackass_%28TV_series%29))*.

I feel like we can do better than this, but is this in the right direction?

Edit: OK, given what the OP has clarified, I add the following two:

- He gaped his maw.
- He fucked his skull.

These are not considered very well defined and are usually something you do to someone else, not to yourself, but it is definitely vulgar.

Comment: Is falling off a balcony really an act of "stupidicide" or "jackassery"? It seems more like horribly unfortunate to me.

Comment: No, not really. The OP said the character *killed himself*, so I was assuming it was his fault.  Perhaps the OP can clarify whether it is an unfortunate accident or the result of poor decisions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I included edit in the question. The expression should not imply person's fault or stupidity.

Comment: @JAM: In the original context, I assumed as david did. In other words, they fell off the balcony because they were drunk and planking, or they touched a high-voltage line because they were [shoe tossing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoe_tossing). Tragic accidents wouldn't qualify.

Answer (score 2):

Okay... my suggestion may not be a "direct hit," but it might be in the right neighborhood.

I propose ***chlorinated the gene pool***, or ***nominated himself for a Darwin Award***.

- These terms are not exactly vulgar, but they might be considered rather edgy.
- They don't necessarily involve self-inflicted death, but they often do.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Awards):

> The Darwin Awards are a tongue-in-cheek honor .. [that] recognize individuals who have contributed to human evolution by self-selecting themselves out of the gene pool via death or sterilization due to their own (unnecessarily foolish) actions. The criterion for the awards states, "In the spirit of Charles Darwin, the Darwin Awards commemorate individuals who protect our gene pool by making the ultimate sacrifice of their own lives. Darwin Award winners eliminate themselves in an extraordinarily idiotic manner, thereby improving our species' chances of long-term survival."
>
> Accidental self-sterilization also qualifies; however, the site notes: "Of necessity, the award is usually bestowed posthumously."

You can read about a few Darwin award nominees at [this website](http://www.bestnursingmasters.com/darwin-awards/). The expression "chlorinating the gene pool" is used as a subtitle for [this Darwin Awards book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0452295637).

## EDIT:

When I first answered this question, I was under the (false) assumption that the O.P. was looking for a vulgar way to say that someone had taken his own life through some act of stupidity. It's since been clarified that's not the case.

Someone else has suggested *bit the dust*; I'll add ***bought the farm***, which could perhaps only be considered [mildly vulgar](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vulgar) at best, but is used to describe when a person has met some untimely or ill-fated death, not necessarily through some fault of their own. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bought+the+farm) says:

> **buy the farm** [*Slang*]: To die, especially suddenly or violently.

It's not as vulgar as some of the other suggestions, but I believe it has a rightful place in the conversation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I included edit in the question. The expression should not imply person's fault or stupidity.

Comment: @nuoritoveri: Okay, one other question then. Should the answer *exclude* stupidity? Or should it include _both_ at-fault and accidental deaths?

Comment: It does not have to exclude stupidity, but should not imply it.

Comment: This is not really vulgar by current norms.

Comment: @david.smith: Agreed. I said as much in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most vulgar ways I can think of to describe someone's death is just to describe it in graphic detail.  Anything less is generally a euphemism to avoid, well, vulgarity.  So, "he jumped in front of a train, splatted all over the front window and screamed in agony for a few seconds as his colon flew past his head" is always going to be more vulgar than "he committed suicide".

Comment: No, it's more descriptive but it's not more vulgar.

Comment: @JohnP: It's also more offensive, which apparently is the sense in which OP was using *vulgar*. But I agree with you in general.